# Unable to get iam policy for a project's Artifact Registry in GCP using Python GCloud API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-iam, google-cloud-python, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to access the IAM permissions for the artifact registry of one of my projects through artifactregistry_v1 python API fro GCP.

```
name_val = "projects/" + REGISTRY_NAME
    artifact_registry_client = artifactregistry_v1.ArtifactRegistryClient(
    credentials=credentials
)
    req = iam_policy_pb2.GetIamPolicyRequest(resource=name_val)
    policy = artifact_registry_client.get_iam_policy(request=req)
    print(policy)
```

When I try this code, I get an error: 400 requests contain an invalid argument for the line request=req.

But if I just pass the resource into the get_iam_policy function, I get an error saying  it got an unexpected keyword argument 'resource'.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.services.artifact_registry.ArtifactRegistryClient#google_cloud_artifactregistry_v1_services_artifact_registry_ArtifactRegistryClient_get_iam_policy) documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Based on this documentation on [`get_iam_policy`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/artifactregistry/latest/google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.services.artifact_registry.ArtifactRegistryClient#google_cloud_artifactregistry_v1_services_artifact_registry_ArtifactRegistryClient_get_iam_policy), when you make the request, the variable for the request argument(s) should be the same when you make the request.

In your sample code, it should look like this:

```py
name_val = "projects/" + REGISTRY_NAME
    artifact_registry_client = artifactregistry_v1.ArtifactRegistryClient(
    credentials=credentials
)
    req = iam_policy_pb2.GetIamPolicyRequest(resource=name_val)
    policy = artifact_registry_client.get_iam_policy(req=req) # the code should look like this
    print(policy)
```